# Different top-bar heights based on media query

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've set the `$topbar-height` variable to a specific value, that is higher than the default value.

For the mobile version I'd like to keep the default value.

How can I do that?

I can't just change the height value of `.topbar`, as this variable is used by Foundation across many other attribues of the topbar and its children elements (line-height, padding, margin, etc).

Comment: I wish to do the same, but change the color instead of the height. Is your answer below, still the best approach considering it is 3 years later and the moving target tar are of web standards...

Answer (score 2):

I've found out that doing something like that works:

```
@media #{$small} {
  $topbar-height: 85px;
  @import "foundation/components/top-bar";
...
}
```

Maybe is not the cleanest approach (I must check if this produce redundant CSS) but I prefer this what, even though I consider @James answer good as well (probably it's even a cleaner way for what concerns the produced CSS).

I think that an actual `top-bar` mixin would solve this issue: I'll add it as a suggestion.

Comment: +1 - this works, although I agree that it probably creates a bunch of redundant CSS. It'd be nice if the height were configurable at multiple breakpoints, not just overall.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Foundation out of the box. I have done two things in the past to get custom functionality such as this:

1) override the CSS classes in app.scss by appending !important to force the changes to take effect.

or

2) copied the mixins and html class generation Sass from the zurb-foundation gem (for example `foundation/components/top-bar.scss`)
to either app.scss or a new file, then modify app.scss so you no longer use the blanket import by commenting it out

```
// @import "foundation";
```

and importing everything else (for development, but only the parts I need for production) with the exception with the file you want to override, in this case

```
// @import "foundation/components/top-bar";
```

Once you do that, you can modify the html generation or the mixins or add media queries for whatever you want to do.

Keep in mind if you make a modification like this it could break with future versions of Zurb Foundation.